# NodeJS program to scrape table columns from Wikipedia

Tags: node.js, cheerio

I am in the process of learning Node JS and how to web scrape. I thought it would be a good approach to extract columns from a wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies

I've been learning about web scraping with Cheerio but am unsure how to code this in NodeJS. I've become familiar with html selectors to identify elements on a page but am not sure how to extract into a program. I plan on extracting this information into a list. I am hoping to extract the Symbol and Security columns on the table on the wiki page.

Below is the code I have compiled and the result I am getting. I have created a const based off a selector on the webpage. I believe it is supposed to return all the values in the column based off the selector.

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var AWS = require("aws-sdk/global");

AWS.config.apiVersions = {
  dynamodb: '2012-08-10'
};

var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const axios = require('axios');
const express = require('express');

async function getStocks() {
  try {
    const url = ' https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies'

    const { data } = await axios({
      method: "GET",
      url: url,
    })

    const $ = cheerio.load(data)
    const elemSelector = '#constituents > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td'

    $(elemSelector).each((parentIdx, parentElem) =>  {
      console.log(parentIdx)
    })
    console.log($)
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
}

getStocks()
```

**Result**

```
[Function: initialize] {


html: [Function: html],
  xml: [Function: xml],
  text: [Function: text],
  parseHTML: [Function: parseHTML],
  root: [Function: root],
  contains: [Function: contains],
  merge: [Function: merge],
  load: [Function: load],
  _root: Node {
    type: 'root',
    name: 'root',
    parent: null,
    prev: null,
    next: null,
    children: [ [Node], [Node] ],
    'x-mode': 'no-quirks'
  },
  _options: { xml: false, decodeEntities: true },
  fn: Cheerio { constructor: [Function: LoadedCheerio] }
}
[Finished in 2.384s]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help. Follow the comments to understand what is happening. You didn't specify how you wanted the data output, so I have them as arrays but you can add code to map the table data with the table headers now that you have the raw data.

```js
// parses HTML
var $ = cheerio.load(data);
// the number of columns you want to target on the table, starting from the left column
var number_of_columns = 2;
// targets the specific table with a selector
var html_table = $('table#constituents');
// gets table header titles; loops through all th data, and pulls an array of the values
var table_header = html_table.find('th').map(function() {return $(this).text().trim();}).toArray();
// removes columns after the number of columns specified
table_header = table_header.slice(0, number_of_columns);
// gets table cell values; loops through all tr rows
var table_data = html_table.find('tbody tr').map(function(tr_index) {
  // gets the cells value for the row; loops through each cell and returns an array of values
  var cells = $(this).find('td').map(function(td_index) {return $(this).text().trim();}).toArray();
  // removes columns after the number of columns specified
  cells = cells.slice(0, number_of_columns);
  // returns an array of the cell data generated
  return [cells];
  // the filter removes empty array items
}).toArray().filter(function(item) {return item.length;});
// output the table headers
console.log('table_header', table_header);
// output the table data
console.log('table_data', table_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

In nodejs you can user puppeteer for your web scraping. it's a very good library with a lot of browser settings and query selectors options!

You can find more about the library reading the documentation at https://pptr.dev/

If you want to integrate it with an API I can help you too.

Comment: I integrated code. Is puppeteer similar to Cheerio?