# Scrape single column from table on Wikipedia using NodeJS Cheerio

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, axios, scrape

I am trying to scrape a column from the table located on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies). I am trying to get the first column, Symbol, and use those symbols in an array in NodeJS. I attempted to scrape only this column using Cheerio and Axios. For some reason, after running the function I do not get any syntax errors but I also do not get any result after execution. I'm not sure if the elements I have loaded are correct or not, but any advice on how I can scrape the Symbol column into an array would be helpful. Below is my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const axios = require("axios");

async function read_fortune_500() {
  try {
    const url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies'

    const { data } = await axios({
      method: "GET",
      url: url,
    })

    const $ = cheerio.load(data)
    const elemSelector = '#constituents > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td'
    $(elemSelector).each((parentIndex, parentElem) => {
      if (parentIndex <= 9){
        $(parentElem).children().each((childIndex, childElem) => {
          console.log($(childElem).text())
        })
      }
    })
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
}

read_fortune_500()
```

**Result**

```
[Finished in 1.238s]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NodeJS program to scrape table columns from Wikipedia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69890934/nodejs-program-to-scrape-table-columns-from-wikipedia)

Answer (score 0):

To help with your original issue:

> For some reason, after running the function I do not get any syntax
> errors but I also do not get any result after execution.

The reason for this is that you are calling an async function in javascript. Because `read_fortune_500` has the `async` keyword, you need to 'wait' for this function to complete. In javascript world, the `read_fortune_500` is actually returning a promise and you need to wait until the promise resolves. You can do that in a couple of ways:

The easiest way to handle this is tp wrap your function call inside an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE):

```js
(async () => {
    await read_fortune_500()
})();
```

In future versions of node you can use await without the need for wrapping it but hopefully that helps.

For the second issue, getting a list of symbols. You need to update the query selector you are using:

```js
const $ = cheerio.load(data)
const elements = $("#constituents > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1)")
elements.each((parentIndex, parentElem) => {
```

The CSS selector is slightly different but the selector above tells cheerio to look inside *each* table row in the DOM and then select the first column in that row.

Full working code below:

```js
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const axios = require("axios");

async function read_fortune_500() {
  try {
    const url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies'

    const { data } = await axios({
      method: "GET",
      url: url,
    })

    const $ = cheerio.load(data)
    const elements = $("#constituents > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1)")
    elements.each((parentIndex, parentElem) => {
      if (parentIndex <= 9){
        $(parentElem).children().each((childIndex, childElem) => {
          console.log($(childElem).text())
        })
      }
    })
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
}

(async () => {
    await read_fortune_500()
})();
```